# Excel formula for finding a column match and writing to that specific adjacent row

Tags: excel, row, match

http://oi60.tinypic.com/30mvcli.jpg

So basically I want to check all values in column B against all values in column A.  If there is a match I want column C to write the value of column in the corresponding row that A is on (as shown in the picture).

Not sure which forumla(s) I need to use to do this.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Todd, I think a simple if statement should work here.

=IF(A1=B1,A1,"")

The above formula will copy the data from A1 into C1 only if A1 is equal to B1.
Enter this formula into C1 and drag it down for as many rows as you need (Excel will change the 1s to 2s etc). Let me know if this works for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1, B:B, 0)), A1, "")
```

Put this to C1. Drag down for as many rows as you need.

Answer (score 0):

In C1 try,

```
=if(countif(b:b, a1), a1, "")
```

[image: CountIf A and B]

Fill down as necessary.